# write regular expression to segregate parameters from pyodbc mssql/mysql database expression

Tags: python, regex

Check parameter match : `<dbtype>[-odbc] '://' <hostname [.FQDN]> ':' <port> '/' <dbname> '?' <user> '&' <pwd>`

```py
p_db = "mssql-odbc://sct-mssql-db.c6p0dl1fqnlk.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:1433/sct_mssql_db?mssql_user'&'schemaconversion"
pattern = re.compile(r"^(\w+)(-odbc)?://([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+[\.a-zA-Z0-9_-]*):?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/?([a-zA-Z0-9_]?[\.a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)\??([\\\.a-z#A-Z0-9_-]*)&?([\\!\.a-zA-Z#0-9_-]*)$")
(dbtype, driver, hostname, port, dbname, user, pwd) = pattern.search(db).groups()
```

This expression is not working for me only in the starting point where it should pick datatype value.

Comment: Try `re.compile(r"^(\w+)(-odbc)?://([\w-][\w.-]*)(?::([a-zA-Z0-9]*))?(?:/(\w[\w.-]*)\?([\w\\.#-]*)'&'([\w\\!.#-]*))?$", re.ASCII)`

Comment: `?` means 0 or 1 of the atom (a single character or 
the content of brackets) before it. Where you have `(foo):?(bar) it matches both `foo:bar` which appears to be what you want, but also `foobar`. I think you don't need most or all of the `?`s in your regex.

Comment: Your code has `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` in a lot of places.  `\w` is a shorthand for that character set and you can shorten and simplify your regex by using it.  Wiktor Stribiżew's comment does that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
pattern = re.compile(r"^(\w+)(-odbc)?://([\w-][\w.-]*)(?::([a-zA-Z0-9]*))?(?:/(\w[\w.-]*)\?([\w\\.#-]*)'&'([\w\\!.#-]*))?$", re.ASCII)
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WJS4en/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars
- `(-odbc)?` - an optional Group 2: `-odbc` string
- `://` - a fixed string
- `([\w-][\w.-]*)` - Group 3: a word char or a hyphen and then zero or more word, `.` or `-` chars
- `(?::([a-zA-Z0-9]*))?` - an optional sequence of a `:` char and then zero or more letters or digits (Group 4)
- `(?:/(\w[\w.-]*)\?([\w\\.#-]*)'&'([\w\\!.#-]*))?` - an optional sequence of

  - `/` - a `/` char
  - `(\w[\w.-]*)` - Group 5: a word char and then zero or more word, `.` or `-` chars
  - `\?` - a `?` char
  - `([\w\\.#-]*)` - Group 6: zero or more word, `.`, `\`, `#` or `-` chars
  - `'&'`  - a fixed string
  - `([\w\\!.#-]*)`  - Group 7: zero or more word, `\`, `!`, `.`, `#` or `-` chars
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Stribizew thanks for nice explanation.